# Eyes killing me after purchasing laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I am new to this site and in need of some information regarding a recent purchase.

I had a HP laptop that broke down before the year was through so I just went to purchase a new one & got a lenovo ideapad. I love this machine but I notice this screen is super matte ( which I hear is better for eyes ) but my eyes have been hurting for the last 4 days since I got it.

Could it still be that I am adjusting back to a screen? I prefer the look of the glossy more but can't afford/find one with those specifications and I have read that matte/anti glare helps better in the long run since I suffer from migraines from time to time.

Has anyone had this problem adjusting back to a laptop? I can barely keep them open! I would hate to return it seeing as I can't find anything else anyway but my eyes are in such pain!

Comment: You should consult with a medical doctor before anything else. The community here has no competence in such matters.

Comment: What specifically is making your eyes hurt when looking at the screen? Is it too bright/too dim, is the text too small / unclear or is there too much contrast? Most of these issues can be resolved with settings.

Comment: How long do you use the laptop for before the pain starts? How long after you stop before it goes away? Is the pain permanent? I'm only asking in case the laptop purchase is coincidental rather than the cause of the pain... it might just be that you need to see an optician and need reading or VDU glasses...

Comment: It could be that the new screen and your eyes just aren't compatible.  Everybody is different.  This doesn't seem like the kind of issue that we can be much help with.

Comment: Since that it is your own reason. Lenovo may not change the laptop for you. I think the most important thing at the moment is to consult with a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

### You could try adjusting settings, but if you are suddenly in pain you might want to see a doctor

First and foremost, if you have pain in your eyes that has suddenly come on, you might want to give some *serious* consideration to seeing a medical professional; particularly if you have changes to your vision or other things like feeling sick etc. This is **not** personalised medical advice; but a health professional will be able to do a proper assessment of your eyes.

You could try adjusting some settings:

- brightness via <kbd>Fn+F11/F12</kbd> (NB based on [this image](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XRxfyKWQL._SL1500_.jpg), your layout may vary)
- brightness/contrast/gamma via: right click on desktop → `Graphic properties` → `Color correction`
- ClearType text via `Start` → (type in search) `Adjust ClearType text`

But really, if the new laptop is giving you significant eye pain you should discuss that with a health professional.